# Trouble with my custom layout for an Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Making a to-do list. Having 2 issues, The not so important issue is that for some reason I can't see the TextView's that I set up as "labels". The more important thing is that when I click the create new task button, my alert pops up, I can put values in my EditText boxes, but when I hit create, it crashes and I get a NullPointer exception saying I'm trying to call getText() on a null object reference. I can't figure out if I'm inflating incorrectly or if I'm not linking the EditTexts to the alert properly. The annoying thing is that my edittext alert box works just fine editing existing list items(that I hardcoded for testing). Here's my layout and activity, I commented the line in which it breaks. Sorry about all the Log.d's I'm really trying to visualize how all this works.

The Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtCreatePriority"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:hint="1"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtCreateItemContent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCreatePriority"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtCreatePriority"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="Do Laundry"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Priority"
        android:id="@+id/lblPriority"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtCreatePriority"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="23dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Task to-do"
        android:id="@+id/lblItemContent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtCreateItemContent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblPriority"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lblPriority"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="23dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListDataSource ds;
    private ListView listViewToDo;
    private Button btnAddNew;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Context context = this;
        Log.d("MainActivity","Attempting to create data source");
        try {
            ds = new ListDataSource();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("MainActivity","Failed to create data source");
        }
        btnAddNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddNew);
        Log.d("Main Activity","Attempting to link empty list view to on screen view");
        listViewToDo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listOfLists);
        Log.d("Main Activity", "Views linked, Attempting to set adapter to listView");
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(new ListDataSourceAdapter(this, ds));
        Log.d("Main Activity", "Successfully set Adapter");
        btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("addItem", "Entered onclick, Attempting to create AlertDialog");
                AlertDialog.Builder addItem = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                Log.d("addItem", "AlertDialog Built, attempting to create inflater");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                addItem.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_item_layout, null));
                Log.d("addItem", "inflater built linking text boxes");
                final TextView txtCreatePriority = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCreatePriority);
                final TextView txtCreateCellContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCreateItemContent);
                final TextView lblPriority = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblPriority);
                final TextView lblItemContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblItemContent);
                addItem.setTitle("Create new item");
                addItem
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "in onClick method, preparing to add entry");
                                // This is where the code breaks
                                ds.getList().add(Integer.valueOf(txtCreatePriority.getText().toString()), new CellContent(Integer.valueOf(txtCreatePriority.getText().toString()) + 1, txtCreateCellContent.getText().toString().trim()));
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "added new entry");
                                ListDataSourceAdapter adapter = new ListDataSourceAdapter(context, ds);
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "reestablished link to adapter");
                                listViewToDo.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "adapter set");
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "DataSetChanged");
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = addItem.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        // add button listener
        listViewToDo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder editItem = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                final EditText edittext = new EditText(context);
                editItem.setTitle("Change item");
                editItem
                        .setMessage("Set new todo item")
                        .setView(edittext)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                            {
                                Log.d("editText onClick","in onClick method, preparing to remove previous entry");
                                ds.getList().remove(position);
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "removed previous entry");
                                ds.getList().add(position, new CellContent(position + 1, edittext.getText().toString().trim()));
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "added new entry");
                                ListDataSourceAdapter adapter = new ListDataSourceAdapter(context,ds);
                                Log.d("editText onClick","reestablished link to adapter");
                                listViewToDo.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "adapter set");
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Log.d("editText onClick", "DataSetChanged");
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = editItem.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling "(EditText)v.findViewById" on the view v.
The view v is the view passed back in the onClickListener, which is the button itself.
Since that button does not contain the EditTexts within it, those views are null. And crash when you try to access them.

I'm a little uncertain where the layout with the edit texts is in this code. Is it in the same layout as the listview, or in create_item_layout?

If its create_item_layout, that needs to be inflated before getting the EditTexts. Use the view you inflate to findViewById.

Comment: Yeah they are in create_item_layout. So I changed the code to call the inflater right after I create it now, and removed the view v, But then I was getting an error that I couldn't cast an EditView to a TextView. So I changed the declarations but I still get a Null Pointer Exception. I edited my code example above to show what I have now. I think I'm still missing the View and inflate connection and how they work in this instance.

Comment: I see what you were saying, I took out my horrible attempt at inflating and put in. 

 View addItemView = View.inflate(context,R.layout.create_item_layout,null);

It works now